# why my code is not reading the input file correctly?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the following input within the code:

```
2,4,6,7,6
2,3,4,3,8
2,3,4,6,7
5,2,3,1,4
6,5,4,7,2
```

but it reads it as all zeros

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

here is my code:

```
double Par[D_one][D_two];

int main(int argc, char** argv){

   const char* input = "file path/.fileName.txt" 
   ifstream file4(input);

   if (!file4)
   {
       cerr << "ERROR: could not open file '" << input  << "' for reading" << endl;

       throw (-1);
   }

   //Transferring data in .txt file to C++
   for (int i = 0; i < D_one; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < D_two; j++)
        file4 >> Par[i][j];

   //Display input
   cout << "input : " << endl;
   cout << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < D_one; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < D_two; j++)
           cout << " " << Par[i][j] << ", ";
   cout << endl;

   cout << endl << endl;
   file4.close();
}
```

Comment: What's `D_one` and `D_two`?

Comment: you are not reading the `,`. This is simpler with `getline` with `,` as delimiter

Comment: there are dimensions of Par matrix. 5 by 5

Comment: please post the real code. The code you posted does not compile. It is not the code that produced the output you posted

Answer (score -2):

Change from double to char. When u read data from text file it's in char type so you need to read a data in a char Par[rows][cols]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

char Par[5][9];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    const char *input = "fileName.txt";
    std::ifstream file4(input);

    if (!file4)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: could not open file '" << input << "' for reading" << std::endl;

        throw(-1);
    }

    // Transferring data in .txt file to C++
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            file4 >> Par[i][j];
            std::cout << Par[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    /*  //Display input
      std::cout << "input : " << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
              std::cout << " " << Par[i][j] << ", ";
      std::cout << std::endl;

      std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;*/
    file4.close();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).